# Facebook Marketing API Leads returning empty data array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

When calling [https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/<ad_id>/leads](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving#bulk-read), I'm receiving an empty data array despite the fact that leads are showing in the Ads Manager dashboard for that ad.

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

To further prove that there should be leads, calling `https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/<ad_id>/insights?fields=ad_name,impressions,actions` does return the correct number of leads:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      ...,
      "actions": [
        ...,
        {
          "action_type": "lead",
          "value": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the problem here? How do I obtain the lead data from the API?